# How to get an error back when file limit is reached? Plupload + asp.net mvc 3 + web.config

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, web-config

I am playing around with plupload and I made a huge file that is 80mb and I am trying to upload it.

plupload looks like it is uploading it. It starts at 0% and goes to 100%.

Now it dies at the server and the reason is because the default limit size is like 4mbs in the web.config controlled by this

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="240" maxRequestLength="102400" />
```

When I set it to a high number like above the file uploads and I hits my break point. If I don't have the above set and upload a large file(over 4mb) It never hit's my break point in my action method.

So how can I tell my users that hey they reached the limit? If I can't get into my methods and at the very least return a message back. Right now they would think that all was well and it uploaded.

I know plupload does have stuff that checks the file size but I treat that like client side validation and now I am trying to do server side validation.

```
 [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Import(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            // never gets here if file is bigger than the web.config size.
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may take a look at the [following blog post](http://ethicaldeveloper.blogspot.com/2008/06/limiting-file-upload-sizes-with-aspnet.html) which suggests handling this exception in the `Application_Error` method.